# Submit without reloading (Ajax, Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I've been studying and trying ajax for a couple of days. This code is totally working when page is reloading, However, my target is when I submit the form, it will not reload.

I've been trying it for couple days and it's really not working. It is submitting and reloading instead of not reloading.

I have provided my code below:

**Views:**

```html
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return post();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="fightIDa" id="fightID" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="FIGHT NUMBER" hidden />
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="arenaID" name="arenaID" hidden />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="fas fa-user mr-2"></i>Handler Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="handlerName" id="handlerName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Handler Name" required />
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
    <!--     <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="fas fa-clipboard mr-2"></i>Position</label> -->
    <!--     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="position" value="MERON" id="meron1"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Rooster Description" required> -->
    <!-- </div> -->

    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="fas fa-clipboard mr-2"></i>Rooster Specifications</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bodyColor" id="bodyColor" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Body Color" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="legColor" id="legColor" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Leg Color" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="wingSpan" id="wingSpan" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Wing Span" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="weight" id="weight" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Weight" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tailColor" id="tailColor" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="tailColor" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="breed" id="breed" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Breed" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
    <!--     <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Rooster Photo</label> -->
    <!--     <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Date Added" required> -->
    <!-- </div> -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pic_file"><i class="fas fa-images mr-2"></i>Rooster Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="roosterPhoto" class="form-control btn-sm" id="roosterPhoto" />
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
    <!--     <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date Added</label> -->
    <!--     <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="" id="addedBy" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Date Added" required> -->
    <!-- </div> -->

    <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
    <!--     <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="fas fa-at mr-2"></i>Added By</label> -->
    <!--     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addedBy"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="USERNAME" disabled> -->
    <!-- </div> -->

    <!-- select -->

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-danger text-bold float-right" id="meron" value="save">Submit</button>
</form>
<p id="status"></p>

<!-- end form -->
```

**Controller:**

```php
public function creates(){
            
  $id = $this->input->post('arenaID');
  $data = array ( 
      'fightID' => '0',
      'handlerName' => $this->input->post('handlerName'),
      'position' => 'meron',
      'bodyColor' => $this->input->post('bodyColor'),
      'legColor' => $this->input->post('legColor'),
      'wingSpan' => $this->input->post('wingSpan'),
      'weight' => $this->input->post('weight'),
      'breed' => $this->input->post('breed'),
      'tailColor' => $this->input->post('tailColor'),
      'addedBy' => $this->session->userdata('uid'),
      'fightStatus' => 'on-queue',
      'arenaID' =>$id,
      'roosterPhoto' =>  $this->upload(),
  );
  $this->db->insert('fight_entries', $data);
  echo 'Added successfully.';
}
```

**Script & Ajax:**

```js
function post() {
    var fightID = document.getElementById("fightID").value;
    var arena = document.getElementById("arenaID").value;
    var handlername = document.getElementById("handlerName").value;
    var bodycolor = document.getElementById("bodyColor").value;
    var legcolor = document.getElementById("legColor").value;
    var wing = document.getElementById("wingSpan").value;
    var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var tail = document.getElementById("tailColor").value;
    var breed = document.getElementById("breed").value;
    var photo = document.getElementById("roosterPhoto").value;

    if (fightID && arenaID && handlerName && bodyColor && legColor && wingSpan && weight && tailColor && breed && roosterPhoto)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=site_url('arena/creates')?>",
            data: {
                fightID: fightID,
                arenaid: arenaID,
                handler_Name: handlerName,
                body_Color: bodyColor,
                leg_Color: legColor,
                wing_Span: wingSpan,
                weight: weight,
                tail_Color: tailColor,
                breed: breed,
                rooster_Photo: roosterPhoto
            },
            success: function(response) {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Form Submitted Successfully";
            }
        });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `it's really not working` - what does that mean? Explicitly describe the problem. Do you mean the form is submitting as a normal HTML form, and the page reloading, instead of being handled by JS and the page not changing in the browser? What is `doSomethingBeforeClosing()`, where is that code? PS - pls try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That's a big form, probably 1 input would do for the sake of getting this working right? Same with JS, and unless the problem is with the PHP a 1-line `echo 'Added successfully.';` method would do?

Comment: Hello, first, it is submitting as a normal html form. (Reloading). As far as I know, it is not triggering my ajax/script code. Second, i removed doSomethingBeforeClosing(). It is irrelevant code. My bad. Thank you

Comment: OK, so try some debugging - any clues in your browser devtools? Errors on the console?  Try to simplify the problem as much as possible - strip the commented out HTML out of your form, strip out all but 1 input. Is your JS really being called?  `$('form').submit(function(e) { alert('hello!'); };` is enough to test that. If yes, incrementally add code back to test. `e.preventDefault();` is the key to stopping normal form submission, you already have that so the problem is somewhere else ...

Comment: Hello, i updated it. This time, it's much better than before. Please, take a look at it. 

Submit button is not working.

Comment: no variable of roosterPhoto in your javascirpt code.  may be it is photo.

Comment: please change it and check i think it works for you.

Comment: I changed it already and nothings happens. :/ Please see the screenshot.

https://prnt.sc/x4evz2

Comment: var roosterPhoto = $("input[name='roosterPhoto']").val();

Comment: var photo = $("input[name='roosterPhoto']").val(); this line change with above one

Comment: `it's much better` - what does that mean? `Submit button is not working` - what does that mean? AJAX is really very simple, [here's a super basic *working* example I just made](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/z5u84wes/).  Copy that, get it working.  Once it works, incrementally start changing it to match what you need.  If it stops working, go back a step and work out what broke it.

1) Don't use inline JS like `onsubmit()`, modern convention is to keep your JS separate, like you had before; 2) As I already suggested, debug!! Any clues in your browser devtools? Errors on the console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `false` bottom of the submit function
like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var handlerName = $("input[name='handlerName']").val();
    var bodyColor = $("input[name='bodyColor']").val();
    var legColor = $("input[name='legColor']").val();
    var wingSpan = $("input[name='wingSpan']").val();
    var weight = $("input[name='weight']").val();
    var breed = $("input[name='breed']").val();
    var tailColor = $("input[name='tailColor']").val();
    var roosterPhoto = $("input[name='roosterPhoto']").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?= site_url('arena/creates')?>",
        data: {
            handlerName: handlerName,
            bodyColor: bodyColor
                legColor: legColor,
            wingSpan: wingSpan,
            weight: weight,
            breed: breed,
            tailColor: tailColor
                roosterPhoto: roosterPhoto
        },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function () {
            alert('Something is wrong');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });

    return false;

}
</script>
```

Comment: put an id for your form and change the form id in jquery as well I think it will work